# Laravel 5.2 crud in ajax method

Tags: laravel

Hello I am trying to do a laravel crud with ajax can anyone please tell me the refrence link any materials which can be help full for me T
Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is not a good type of questions to ask in stackoverflow,

anyway,

use this to generate models/migrations/views/controllers

https://github.com/appzcoder/crud-generator

and then just change the forms to add the ajax functionality..etc

ofc you can do that with jquery to make easyer